# How can I get my source code back after I exported on .JAR file and after that I erased the project from the Workspace?

Tags: java, jar, runnable-jar

I exported a project from Eclipse and then I tried to run'it in my machine and I couldn't. I readed some articles and I realized that I exported the program on a wrong way, (I'm using Eclipse as mi IDE) Eclipse gives you the option to export the project whit the (Runnable.JAR) option  and the (.JAR extension), both are different. I thought the right way It was .JAR extension, but It wasn't, I tried with another project the (Runnable.JAR) and It worked. but I erased my priory project from the workspace of Eclipse(the one the I imported with the .JAR extension),and I've tried to import the program with the .JAR extension and it works but it just appear the compiled file, I can't run it. How can I convert the (.JAR to Runnable.JAR) or at least use it?

Comment: Look into using source control like Github.  Always keep your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the only options you have are to either attempt to recover the deleted workspace, decompile your code, or restart the project.

To decompile your code I suggest either using [this](http://www.javadecompilers.com/), or [this](http://jd.benow.ca/), both should do what you want, but I've always had good luck with the 2nd option. As long as you haven't obfuscated your code, this should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked.